# Replace with $$ in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace all occurences of a particular string with $$ in javascript.

However when I attempt the replace it only replaces a single character
http://jsfiddle.net/PrZ9y/

```
text = "sfsd";
text =text.replace(/sf/gi,"\$\$");
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML=text;
```

This for example outputs `$sd`. The correct output should be `$$sd`

I also tried

```
text =text.replace(/sf/gi,"$$");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$` is reserved for regular expression, doubling-up on `$` will escaped it's intended purpose.

```
text = "sfsd";
text = text.replace(/sf/gi,"$$$$");
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Which is completely ridiculous, of course XD Backslash escapes everything else, including in regex patterns. But yup, this is correct. +1

Comment: Look at Java's `printf()`: You have to type `%` twice to actually print it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: `\$` is resolved **before** the string value is passed to `replace`. And since `\$` is an invalid escape sequence and equivalent to `$`, all the string value the function receives is `$$`. Not much it can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Dollar sign has a special meaning, it means the number of captured group when used in conjuction with a number, like $1. $$ is just the literal for $, the first $ will play the role of escape character. Use $$$$ for $$.

More info:
http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.11

Answer (score 1):

`$$` is reserved just like `$&` is reserved, so use three of them:

```
text=text.replace(/sf/gi,"$$$");
```

Comment: Actually, only certain patterns of `$` followed by another characters are reserved. That includes `$$` or `$&`. And that's why this solution works. A single/sole `$` has no specific meaning (and is taken literally). Nice!

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, I am going to edit my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your html as:

```
<div id="x">sf sd</div>
<div id="wmd-input"></div>
```

Then, change your code to:

```
text = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML;
text = text.replace(/sf/gi,"$$$$");
document.getElementById("wmd-input").innerHTML = text;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrZ9y/2/).

As @Mr Polywhirl noted, you need to use another `$` to escape the `$` and get one literal `$` sign.